# How can I make this INI file into a listview in Autohotkey

Tags: loops, listview, autohotkey, ini

I want to arrange this INI file into a listview where the SECTION is the first column and every key creates another column. I thought I had it with this code but the second column shows all the keys together instead of separated. Can someone help me separate them into individual columns. Also I am not very advanced in AHK, so if you can comment flag your steps would be highly appreciated!

```
#SingleInstance, force
#NoEnv

FileDelete,test.ini
FileAppend,
(
[PROJECT-1]
Company=Company A
Remarks=Info about Project 1
Status=Current
Value=Some Value not needed
[PROJECT-2]
Company=Company B
Remarks=Info about Project 2
Status=Late
Values=Some Value not needed
)
,test.ini


GUI, ADD, Listview, w600, PROJECT|COMPANY|REMARKS|STATUS
IniRead, OutputVarProjects, test.ini
; MsgBox % OutputVarProjects

Loop, parse, OutputVarProjects, `n ;shows sections
    {
    LVDATA:=""  
    IniRead, OutputVarSection, test.ini, %A_LoopField%
    ; MsgBox % OutputVarSection
    Loop, parse, OutputVarSection, `n
    LVDATA .= StrSplit(A_LoopField,"=").2 ","   
    ; MsgBox % LVDATA   
    LV_Add("", A_loopfield, lvdata)
    }
    Gui, show
    Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know what the key names are going to be, my suggestion would be to statically read each of them individually. Dynamically reading the keys of sections is not a guarantee they will appear in that order down the line.

```
#SingleInstance, force
#NoEnv

FileDelete,test.ini
FileAppend,
(
[PROJECT-1]
Company=Company A
Remarks=Info about Project 1
Status=Current
Value=Some Value not needed
[PROJECT-2]
Company=Company B
Remarks=Info about Project 2
Status=Late
Values=Some Value not needed
)
,test.ini


Gui, Add, Listview, w600, PROJECT|COMPANY|REMARKS|STATUS
IniRead, projects, test.ini
Loop, parse, projects, `n ;shows sections
{
    sect := A_LoopField
    IniRead, keys, test.ini, % sect
    IniRead, company, test.ini, % sect, Company, %A_Space%
    IniRead, remarks, test.ini, % sect, Remarks, %A_Space%
    IniRead, status, test.ini, % sect, Status, %A_Space%
    LV_Add("", sect, company, remarks, status)
}
Loop, % LV_GetCount("Col")
    LV_ModifyCol(A_Index, "autoHdr")
Gui, show
return

GuiClose:
 ExitApp
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you

Comment: It took a while but my reputation has grown. I have upvoted and checked.